# How do I take a screnshot using sikuli_cpython?

Tags: python, sikuli

I know how to take a screenshot with Sikuli IDE. Currently I am using  [sikuli_cpython](https://github.com/kevlened/sikuli_cpython). I am trying to do the same:

```
import sikuli
my_screen = sikuli.DesktopScreenRegion()
my_capture = my_screen.capture()

print my_capture
<java.awt.image.BufferedImage at 0x66ef7b0 jclass=java/awt/image/BufferedImage jself=<LocalRef obj=0xbe79688 at 0x62fda00>>
```

That's where I don't know how to save the screenshot.

```
dir(my_capture)
'BITMASK', 'OPAQUE', 'SCALE_AREA_AVERAGING', 'SCALE_DEFAULT', 'SCALE_FAST', 
'SCALE_REPLICATE', 'SCALE_SMOOTH', 'TRANSLUCENT', 'TYPE_3BYTE_BGR',     
'TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR', 'TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR_PRE', 'TYPE_BYTE_BINARY', 'TYPE_BYTE_GRAY',
'TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED', 'TYPE_CUSTOM', 'TYPE_INT_ARGB', 'TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE',    
'TYPE_INT_BGR', 'TYPE_INT_RGB', 'TYPE_USHORT_555_RGB', 'TYPE_USHORT_565_RGB', 
'TYPE_USHORT_GRAY', 'UndefinedProperty', '__class__', '__cls_storage', '__delattr__', 
'__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', 
'__javaclass__', '__javaconstructor__', '__module__', '__new__', '__pyx_vtable__', 
'__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', 
'__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'addTileObserver', 'coerceData', 'copyData', 
'createGraphics', 'equals', 'flush', 'getAccelerationPriority', 'getAlphaRaster', 
'getCapabilities', 'getClass', 'getColorModel', 'getData', 'getGraphics', 'getHeight', 
'getMinTileX', 'getMinTileY', 'getMinX', 'getMinY', 'getNumXTiles', 'getNumYTiles', 
'getProperty', 'getPropertyNames', 'getRGB', 'getRaster', 'getSampleModel', 
'getScaledInstance', 'getSource', 'getSources', 'getSubimage', 'getTile', 
'getTileGridXOffset', 'getTileGridYOffset', 'getTileHeight', 'getTileWidth', 
'getTransparency', 'getType', 'getWidth', 'getWritableTile', 'getWritableTileIndices', 
'hasTileWriters', 'hashCode', 'isAlphaPremultiplied', 'isTileWritable', 'notify', 
'notifyAll', 'releaseWritableTile', 'removeTileObserver', 'setAccelerationPriority', 
'setData', 'setRGB', 'toString', 'wait']
```

Comment: Can you show me the result of dir(my_capture)?

Comment: There is just sikuli_script.py, which is the script that contains the code I mentioned.

Comment: No.I mean check properties of my_capture. dir() is a built-in function in Python.

Comment: I have updated my question with the output of dir(my_capture).

Comment: It seems there is no api for you to store it as an image file...

Answer (score 0):

Use the following (assuming sikuli was imported with a wildcard like in the docs):

```
img = Screen().capture()
filePath = os.path.join(r"c:\path\to\place\image", "imageOutput.png")
shutil.move(img, filePath)
print "File is now locatede at %s" % filePath
```

You have the image so far, but you then need to move the image from the location it was saved to a location of your choosing.